# Using object declared in a method in another implementation in another file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview method:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

that declares: `NSInteger row = [indexPath row];` with the above  method in the file TableView.m and I want to use the value of 'row' in another file called SecondView.m and I do not know how to allow the value of row to be used in the other file and make it public for the whole project to us it - I want to use it in an `if` statement in another file.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scope of the variable you want to use is limited to inside one of your methods, you cannot use it outside.

You'll have to make it a member variable and query it from an instance of the class.

```
@interface MyTable{
  NSInteger row;   //Member variable
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger row; //Making it a property allows it to be accessed from other classes
@end
...
@implementation
@synthesize row; //Used in conjunction with @property
....
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    row = [indexPath row]; //sets the variable you want to use
    ...
}
....
@end
```

other class:

```
[myTable row];  //Use the variable
```

Comment: It says there's an undeclared identifier in the code... I don't want to call it like [myTable row], I want to call it like if(row==1){NSLog@"Hello";}

Comment: What is the undeclared identifier?

Comment: That's because you have nothing called row. The only solution I see to your problem is to use the code I provided and call `if ([myTable row] == 1){NSLog(@"Hello");}`

Comment: Not the other class .m file - it's declared in the first file - TableView.m and I would like access to it in the SecondView.m.

Comment: In `SecondView.m` you'll need to make an instance of `TableView.m` and use that: `TableView *myTable = [[TableView alloc] init];`